# How do I cancel an Android http request?

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

I'm using `AsyncTask` to initalize `AndroidHttpClient` and execute a POST request in `doInBackground()`. I'd like the user to be able to cancel the request by pressing the back button. `AsyncTask` has a `cancel()` method which only changes the boolean return value of `isCancelled()` and then waits for `doInBackground()` to finish before calling `onCancelled()`. This means that `AsyncTask` leaves it up to the `doInBackground()` method to continuously check whether the task has been cancelled (using `isCancelled()`). If it has been cancelled, `doInBackground()` should return prematurely prematurely. The problem I'm having is that 99% the execution of the worker thread in `doInBackground()` stops on:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request[0]);
```

because this synchronous function call encapsulates the network aspects of the request. How can I cancel the request midway through?

I'm considering trying to change the timeout time during the request, but this seems thread unsafe.

I'm also considering overriding `AsyncTask`'s `cancel()` method, which may work better.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: this will shut down the whole client, not the individual request

Answer (score 19):

The correct way to abort a request with the AndroidHttpClient API is to call `abort()` on the request object that you pass into `httpClient.execute()`.  This will cause the `execute()` call to throw an `IOException`, and the request's `isAborted()` call to begin returning true.  The `abort()` call is defined in the `AbortableHttpRequest` interface, which basically all of the interesting request classes implement (`HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc).

`AsyncTask.cancel(true)` doesn't cancel the request, because `AndroidHttpClient.execute()` doesn't block in a way that `Thread.interrupt()` will do anything to stop (the thread is not waiting to join another thread, waiting on a mutex, or sleeping).  `Thread.interrupt()` does NOT stop blocking I/O.

In my testing, calling `httpClient.close()` or `httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()` does nothing to stop the currently-executing request, but I didn't research deeply to try and find out why.

Comment: Occasionally, I will get an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when doing this.  My HTTP request is already running in an AsyncTask, should I not be accessing the request object in the UI thread to call abort on it?

Comment: The general solution of calling abort() was not sufficient for me.  I followed ayblin's solution and that finally worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007731/how-to-cancel-defaulhttpclient-execution-process-in-multithread

Comment: I avoided the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` by moving my calls to `HttpGet.cancel()` onto a background thread. So annoying. :(

Answer (score 2):

Call `HttpPost`'s or `HttpGet`'s `abort()` method. You can abort the request which throws a (I forget which particular) exception. If you're using a `ClientConnectionManager` you'll want to set `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")`, otherwise subsequent requests will just hang. The connection keep alive issue still exists all the way up to at least 4.1.1.

Answer (score -1):

Actually `AsyncTask.cancel(boolean interruptIfRunning)` can be called using `true` as the parameter to terminate the thread.

Comment: This does not interupt the request, do in background finishes.

Comment: It only attempts to cancel the request, it doesn't guarantee it. Forcefully terminating a thread is generally a bad idea, hence this behaviour.

Comment: I was able to do this and it actually aborts. My approach uses **CloseableHttpClient** and its related classes. Checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007731/how-to-cancel-defaulhttpclient-execution-process-in-multithread/21915242#21915242