# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

Good day!

I need help!

I develop app for android with integration the IIS(SharePoint).
And when i run this code(Code 2), i get ERROR

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

I run this code in firstActivity in method onCreate(Code 1)

Version httpclient - 4.3;

Code 1

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    new HttpsClietn();
    }
}).run();
```

Code 2

```
package com.example.HttpsMy;

import android.os.Environment;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;


import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class HttpsClietn {
    HttpsClietn() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("Grigoriy.Polyakov","password", "", "domain.kz"));

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://serveer.domain.kz");


       HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
               .setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory())
               .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
               .setSslcontext(getContext())
               .build();

        System.out.println(client.execute(httpget,context).getStatusLine());

    }

    SSLContext getContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        //new File("key/keystore.p12"), "1234"
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

        InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/kvv/keystore.p12"));
        keyStore.load(keyInput, "1234".toCharArray());
        keyInput.close();

        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "1234".toCharArray());

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        return context;
    }

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory getFactory() throws CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(getContext());
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

Google Android ships with an extremely outdated (pre BETA 4.0) fork of Apache HttpClient. Due to the presence of old classes on the classpath the stock version of HttpClient fails to initialize correctly unless all classes are moved to another namespace ('org.apache.http' -> 'thank.you.google.http')

One way of making sure the stock version of Apache HttpClient does not overlap with its original namespace is repackaging it with the [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), use [the port](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) developed by Dirk Boye, or the [official port of Apache HttpClient to Google Android](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: thanks! how i can change namespace(move this to others dir), if not recompile httpclient

Comment: @G1yyK: This is a different question, which has been answered on more than one occasion already. Anyway, I added another section to my original answer with details on repackaging options.

Comment: I came accross a very similar issue. What exactly does it mean to repackeage the HttpClient and how exactly do I do that (I tried to look it up but there is no guide on how to do it - at least I couldn't find one)

Answer (score 0):

For android remove all httpclient and httpcore dependencies and add

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'    // gradle depedencies
```

in your build.gradle file