# Win10 supports selenium3.0.1?

Tags: selenium-grid

Is selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar compatible with Windows 10 OS ?

I am able to run a simple java program, getting below error on launching Firefox browser. Tried using TestNG, but facing same issue

Code :

```
package com.riversad.violet;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DemoTests {
    public void sampleTest1(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Auto Violet Work Space\\VioletAutomation\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    }
    public void tests() {
        System.out.println("hellow world");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoTests dt=new DemoTests();
        dt.sampleTest1();
        dt.tests();
    }
}
```

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>         at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:250)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:227)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:92)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:71)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:59)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:49)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
>         at com.riversad.violet.DemoTests.sampleTest1(DemoTests.java:25)
>         at com.riversad.violet.DemoTests.main(DemoTests.java:41)

Comment: 1. Yes windows 10 support selenium 3.0.1

2. From what I can see from your code you use only WebDriver API so you do not need selenium-server  - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

3. show us exception from code that you pasted here because now we cannot see which lines of code cause exception

Comment: Exception is caught in "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();"

Comment: What do you use for building your project? Maven? Gradle?java.lang.NoSuchFieldError is often throw some dependency is included more then one time in different versions. See for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330848/httpclient-example-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-inst or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921077/nosuchfielderror-instance-at-org-apache-http-impl-io-defaulthttprequestwriterfac.

Comment: I am not using Maven or Gradle. I just go to Project-->Clean. Hope this will build my project. And i am using the latest firefox and chrome version with Selenium 3.0.1 jar file

Comment: Do you use any other external libraries?

Comment: Yes, what are the libraries that i should have? I have used
1.selenium-java-3.0.1.jar
2.selenium-server-3.0.1.jar
3.selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
4.testng-6.9.9.jar

Comment: First of all you do not need selenium-servers jars (I told about it in first comment)
Does your code work on selenium 2?
Did you try use different browser than firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue while using webdriver with selenium 3.0.1 on my Windows 10 machine.

Download older version selenium webdriver from [Selenium Downlaod][1].
Search for **jcommander-1.48.jar** from the downloaded zip file and add this jar into your current project.

This should fix the *NoSuchFieldError* and your project should compile successfully.